# Trigger event when the select is changed

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I'm using JQuery UI in order to display a select drop-down menu with icons for each option. I would like to trigger an event when the user click on an option.

Here is a snippet : http://jsfiddle.net/L8p5n41j/

My HTML :

```
    $(function() {

      $.widget("custom.iconselectmenu", $.ui.selectmenu, {
        change: function(event, ui) {
          alert("TEST");
        },
        _renderItem: function(ul, item) {
          var li = $("<li>", {
            text: item.label
          });

          if (item.disabled) {
            li.addClass("ui-state-disabled");
          }

          $("<span>", {
              style: item.element.attr("data-style"),
              "class": "ui-icon " + item.element.attr("data-class")
            })
            .appendTo(li);

          return li.appendTo(ul);
        }
      });


      $("#people")
        .iconselectmenu()
        .iconselectmenu("menuWidget")
        .addClass("ui-menu-icons avatar");
    });
```

My JQuery :

```
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

    <select name="people" id="people">
      <option value="1" data-class="avatar" data-style="background-image: url(&apos;http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/b3e04a46e85ad3e165d66f5d927eb609?d=monsterid&amp;r=g&amp;s=16&apos;);">John Resig</option>
      <option value="2" data-class="avatar" data-style="background-image: url(&apos;http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/e42b1e5c7cfd2be0933e696e292a4d5f?d=monsterid&amp;r=g&amp;s=16&apos;);">Tauren Mills</option>
      <option value="3" data-class="avatar" data-style="background-image: url(&apos;http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/bdeaec11dd663f26fa58ced0eb7facc8?d=monsterid&amp;r=g&amp;s=16&apos;);">Jane Doe</option>
    </select>
```

Comment: I made you the snippet I meant.

Comment: Since your using SelectMenu in your Widget, you can make use of the standard `select` event for this widget: http://api.jqueryui.com/selectmenu/#event-select

Comment: What function or action do you want to call when `select` is triggered?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider the following code: http://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/brsfmk5d/5/

```
$(function() {
  $.widget("custom.iconselectmenu", $.ui.selectmenu, {
    _renderItem: function(ul, item) {
      var li = $("<li>", {
        text: item.label
      });
      if (item.disabled) {
        li.addClass("ui-state-disabled");
      }
      $("<span>", {
        style: item.element.attr("data-style"),
        class: "ui-icon " + item.element.attr("data-class")
      })
      .appendTo(li);
      return li.appendTo(ul);
    }
  });

  $("#people").iconselectmenu({
    select: function(e, ui) {
      console.log("Selected: " + ui.item.label);
    }
  })
  .addClass("ui-menu-icons avatar");
});
```

When an item is Selected, the `select` callback is triggered and you can see the selected label in the Console.

> **change( event, ui )** Type: selectmenuchange
>
> Triggered when the selected item has changed. Not every `select` event will fire a change event.
>
> **select( event, ui )** Type: selectmenuselect
>
> Triggered when a menu item is selected.

Hope that helps.